# messed up sshd_config, so removed openssh-server, installed openssh-server, Not replacing deleted config file /etc/ssh/sshd_config

Tags: ssh, openssh

I messed up sshd_config and did not make a copy.
So I removed openssh-server, then installed openssh-server.
The installation complained with message.
**Not replacing deleted config file /etc/ssh/sshd_config**

Any suggestions for how to reinstall openssh-server?

### On ubuntu 18.04

Somehow microk8s and rcopy also got uninstalled when I removed openssh-server.  yikes, completely unexpected side effect.

Is there a recovery mode of ubuntu 18.04 where it will fix things when they get this badly messed up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

`sudo apt-get purge openssh-server`

it works for me:)

> To purge a package means to delete it and its configuration files

Answer (score 3):

You have to ask APT to replace the configuration file by using command below

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confask" install --reinstall openssh-server
```

Comment: Thank you N0rbert for your solution.  I tried it but it complained: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 43 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
E: Internal Error, No file name for openssh-server:amd64

Comment: if i drop --reinstall, i get the error Not replacing deleted config file /etc/ssh/sshd_config dpkg: error processing package openssh-server (--configure): installed openssh-server package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1 –